# PHP ZF2 mcrypt_encrypt goes to writeClose

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, mcrypt

Using Zend Framework 2 I have had invalid function calls go directly to Session.writeClose.  However, from what I can tell this call is valid:

```
        $encryptedData = mcrypt_encrypt(static::MCRYPT_CIPHER, $key, $data, static::MCRYPT_MODE, $initializationVector);
```

When I get these falling directly to writeClose I can never figure out what the real issue is.  It gets lost in the closing of the session.  Does anyone have any pointers about how to figure out what the real issue is?  Try..catches don't work because there is no error.  There is just going to closing of the session.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid" function call exactly? The error message is quite important ...

Comment: A function that does not exist anywhere or using a function name with the incorrect # of parameters is what I mean by "invalid".  And that's just it, the error message IS important but I never get one.  I just end up going directly to writeClose.  It has not been an issue before now since I just fixed the function but in this case, this one appears to be valid.

Comment: If it says the function doesn't exist, then you most likely don't have the mcrypt extension installed or it's not enabled in php.ini; I don't see how it could have invalid parameter count ...

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear.  mcrypt_encrypt DOES exist and the parameters are correct.  Nothing says the function does not exist.  That is just the usual issue when I go to SessionManager.writeClose().  So I am trying to figure out why I am going to writeClose() now.  How do I determine what the underlying cause of this is.  That is the question really.  Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final analysis of this was that whenever I attempt to call a function that does not exist, or a function with invalid parameters it goes directly to writeClose(). Now when I see that behavior I know to look at my function call and make sure it is valid.